# Split Pandas Dataframe into bands

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a large pandas dataframe. It is

```
                                         Turnover      Outstanding
10c4d42c-72e5-4228-8760-1525f1efe1d8    2.262946e+05    196863.00
236ac7d7-e971-4599-b22d-d54880014914    3.303953e+06    1351439.03
bc50f973-9218-45bd-a297-111781f1a359    2.541676e+06    465144.46
fac0d84b-dbaa-42fb-8779-f36cfc52d20c    4.301824e+05    30054.26
46fc245a-e0cc-4c39-b0d5-e8490e204ecc    3.781342e+05    397482.40
... ... ...
dacce0ef-c7c4-4a90-b215-5635bbc25355    2.167455e+06    842684.59
6a9ffb14-9507-48bb-9563-828325e4fa6f    5.673843e+05    321210.31
12d763af-1ca1-4ce7-9995-3a4a6e72c19b    2.536324e+05    132747.83
218031da-5342-4df4-8881-1608dd5cdd7a    2.292235e+05    288300.16
7d47d4fe-a789-415f-a0c2-c1f2b9035f67    1.586166e+07    3689727.98
```

I want to subdivide this dataframe into a dataframe which will be something like:

```
                        0-5K         5-10K        10-15k             450-500k

0-1M                     40           100         75                    0

1-2M                     70           170         87                    0

2-3M
```

Which will essentially be binning the dataframe but based on two different columns. Is there any convenient way of doing this?

Comment: What are the indices and what are the columns?

Comment: Initial dataframe, the long string is the index and turnover and outstanding are columns; in the one i want to do, there should only be a single column, ```Outstanding``` and it should be sort of multi indexed. The values will be count of the values that fall within those bins

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

Define suitable bins for each column (the ones I have choosen are only to demonstrate the idea):

```
bins_turnover = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks([i * 5_000_000 for i in range(6)], closed='left')
bins_outstanding = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks([i* 5_000_000 for i in range(6)], closed='left')
```

Then `groupby` over the respective `cut`s for each column, `count`, and `unstack` the result:

```
df['Count'] = 1
df = df.Count.groupby([pd.cut(df.Turnover, bins_turnover),
                       pd.cut(df.Outstanding, bins_outstanding)]).count().unstack()
```

Result

```
Outstanding           [0, 5000000)  ...  [20000000, 25000000)
Turnover                            ...                      
[0, 5000000)                     9  ...                     0
[5000000, 10000000)              0  ...                     0
[10000000, 15000000)             0  ...                     0
[15000000, 20000000)             1  ...                     0
[20000000, 25000000)             0  ...                     0

[5 rows x 5 columns]
```

for sample `df`

```
                                        Turnover  Outstanding
Index                                                        
10c4d42c-72e5-4228-8760-1525f1efe1d8    226294.6    196863.00
236ac7d7-e971-4599-b22d-d54880014914   3303953.0   1351439.03
bc50f973-9218-45bd-a297-111781f1a359   2541676.0    465144.46
fac0d84b-dbaa-42fb-8779-f36cfc52d20c    430182.4     30054.26
46fc245a-e0cc-4c39-b0d5-e8490e204ecc    378134.2    397482.40
dacce0ef-c7c4-4a90-b215-5635bbc25355   2167455.0    842684.59
6a9ffb14-9507-48bb-9563-828325e4fa6f    567384.3    321210.31
12d763af-1ca1-4ce7-9995-3a4a6e72c19b    253632.4    132747.83
218031da-5342-4df4-8881-1608dd5cdd7a    229223.5    288300.16
7d47d4fe-a789-415f-a0c2-c1f2b9035f67  15861660.0   3689727.98
```